# How to find and print duplicate values using ArrayLists, subList(), and contains() methods exclusively

Tags: java

I'm trying to print out duplicate values in a sub-list pulled from an `ArrayList` of `Integer` values. I know I need to use a method that includes a `for` loop, within that an `if` statement, within that the `contains()` method.

So if I had [2, 3, 4, 4, 5], the first iteration would read the value 2 from index 0. Then it would create a sub-list starting from index 1 to the end. So [3, 4, 4, 5]. Then it would check the sub-list, using `contains()` to see if it has a 2 in it. If it does, then 2 is a duplicate.

Then on the next iteration, your index would be 1, and the value would be 3. You'd get a sub-list of [4, 4, 5] and see if it contains 3.

Then index would be 2, and the value would be 4. You'd get a sub-list of [4,5] and see if it contains 3.

And so on. I just don't know how to structure it properly.

```java
//inside the main method
ArrayList<Integer> numList2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
numList2 = dups(numList);
System.out.println("The following numbers were duplicated in the ArrayList: " + numList2);

//Outside main as its own method
public static ArrayList<Integer> dups(ArrayList<Integer> list){
ArrayList<Integer> dupList = new ArrayList<Integer>(list.subList(1, list.size()));
        
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    if(list.contains(list.get(i))){
        dupList.add(list.get(i));
    }
}
return dupList;
```

I understand my code is way wrong and messy. I apologize in advance.

Comment: For the array,  [2, 3, 4, 4, 5], what's the expected output?  You should not think in term of sublist and try to create sublist.  That would be a very slow solution.

Comment: expected output is an array showing only duplicate numbers. In this context: "[4]" Slow solution, yes, but it's what I need done at the moment.

Comment: can there be more than one duplicated numbers?  For example, [1,1,1,2,2,3]?  Would the result be 1,2?

Comment: Yes, that's a great example!

Comment: How would you do it without a computer e. g. on paper? Write each step down, then translate your steps to Java.

Comment: make an arraylist, purposefully add dups, [1,1,1,2,2,3], call a method to plug in the numbers to check for duplicates, return duplicates if any, print duplicates. The thing is, I don't know how to translate that to Java

Comment: Are you allowed to use any data structures other than array list?

Answer (score 0):

Just implement the logic.

```
void findDup(ArrayList<Integer> arrayList) {
    ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
        Integer cur = arrayList.get(i);
        // check whether it has been added to the result set
        if (!result.contains(cur) && arrayList.subList(i + 1, arrayList.size()).contains(cur)) {
            result.add(cur);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(result.get(i));
    }
}
```